# Java DecimalFormat to double

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I'm trying to prevent a java double from printing in scientific notation. I know I can use DecimalFormat for this, but this produces a String. How can I produce an actual double?
I've tried:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
double n = Double.parseDouble(df.format(z));
```

However, this still produces a double in scientific notation.

Comment: A double is not in scientific notation or non-scientific notation. A double is in IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point format. Text representing a double can be in scientific or non-scientific notation. tl;dr print the string.

Comment: Do you realize that a `double` is 64-bit value in memory and that there is no such thing as “a double in scientific notation”? You choose the decimal format at the time of converting to decimal, for printing.

Comment: Can it be done with a `Double` as opposed to a `double`?

Comment: Note: I don't think that `double new = …` is supposed to work.

Comment: Sorry, it's not. Bad example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A format is not a property of a double, the data type. This defines just a set of values.

Printing always requires a conversion to a String, so DecimalFormat is fine.

As for using an entirely different set of decimal fractions as values, see java.math.BigDecimal. This is the set of "all" decimal fractions, with a dynamic number of fractional digits, operations and control of round-off.